# How to get my memory address to print properly in C program?

Tags: c

Just trying to achieve this result from this c program:

A program reverses a sentence that the user puts in. For eg. user inputs "This is a good day". The program outputs, "day good a is This". This works fine with my current code. But i am looking at printing the memory address for each of this word. Could anyone show me how i can do this with my code?

This is a good day
day good a is This

day   0039FBBF
good  0039FBC3
a     0039FBC8
is    0039FBCA
This  0039FBCD

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    printf("======================================================================");
    printf("\nProgram that asks user for a sentence and then it reverses the words");
    printf("\n====================================================================");

    char input[20];
    int i,j;
    
    puts("\n\nEnter the sentence to be reversed::\n");
    gets(input);
    printf("Input   addr: %p\n", input);
    printf("\nThe reversed sentence is:: \n\n");
    _strrev(input);
   
    for(i=0; input[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if (input[i + 1] == ' ' || input[i + 1] == '\0')
        {
            for (j = i; j >= 0 && input[j] != ' '; j--) {
                printf("%c", input[j]);
            }
                printf("    addr: % p\n", &input[j]);
       }
       else
       continue;
       printf(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: `gets` was flagged as obsolete 26 years ago and finally removed from the C language 10 years ago. You need to switch to a source of learning which has been updated this millennium.

Comment: What does the code do now?

Comment: `printf("    addr: % p\n", &input[j])` -> `printf("    addr: %p\n", (void*)&input[j])`. That's the proper portable way to print a memory address. (Note the space between `%` and `p`, which needs to eb removed).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you have a `char` array with a length of 20. This is were you store the input String. After entering "This is a good day" the array would look like this:

```
 0 1              ...               18 19
+---------------------------------------+
|T|h|i|s| |i|s| |a| |g|o|o|d| |d|a|y| | |
+---------------------------------------+
```

The variable `input` basically stores the address to the array. You (and the compiler) know that this array is 20 units "wide" and stores the type `char` this would tell you how much byte per item is used. Lets say a char has a size of 1 byte. You could check this with `sizeof(char)`. This way, you could calculate the address for each item in the array by start_address + index * width or `&input + index * sizeof(char)`. Which is kind of neat.

Another way to get the address of any element in the array would be to write `char* addr = &input[x]` where `x`is the index of the array you want the memory adress from. `char* addr` is a pointer storing the address and `&` is telling C that you want the address of this variable / memory / thingy.

So for this example the word "is" would have the address `&input[5]`.

**TL; DR**

`&input[3]` would give you the address of the 4th letter

`&input[10]` would give you the address of the 11th letter

Comment: `input` is an array-type that on access is converted to a pointer to its first element [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). `sizeof (char)` is defined as `1` (checking doesn't hurt but is superfluous) -- otherwise good answer and good artwork (a picture really is worth 1000 words...) And an easy way to describe pointer-arithmetic is to say *"type controls pointer arithmetic"*, e.g. `char *p` and `p + 1` advances one byte to next char, while `int *p`, `p + 1` advances 4-bytes to the next `int`